# What's a quick way to create SQL tables when starting out?

Tags: sql

I find that creating SQL tables tedious when starting to create a web app (ASP/Python/PHP).

Do you guys know any tools that makes creating tables quicker and faster and easier? Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: What a strange question... What DBMS? for what purpose?

Comment: Huh, Whether you write neat DDl or use a GUI, the tedium is not going to go for you. I personally find just writing the DDL quicker, but the tools were crap / non-existent when I started. Best bet to take the tedium out, is to learn and do more with DB end of your designs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion writing a `CREATE TABLE` statement is **far** less tedious than writing HTML pages.

The recommended approach is to use a ER design tool co create and define your database model. Most (if not all) ER designer can then create the necessary DDL statement directly from the model.

With this approach you also have a documentation of your database model which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tools/libraries you use to create your app.

If you use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping), many ORMs offer you the possibility to create the database with all tables automatically, according to the classes and mappings you defined in your application.